# Multiple Linear Regression Coefficient of Determination

Tags: linear-regression, regression-analysis

[![I just have one question that might be simple but I really appreciate any help!
The question is: Consider now the regression model X1 = γ0 + γ1X2 + γ2D. How can I use the given SPSS output to compute the coefficient of determination for this model][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ2oW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ2oW.png)

Comment: R^2 is the coefficient of determination and has been given in the SPSS output, I don't think you need to compute it unless you want to verify the results of SPSS?

Comment: R^2 is given for the model Y versus the 3 predictors. I want to compute R^2 for the model X1 versus the other 2 predictors.

Comment: You need to run a separate analysis with X1 as the dependent variable and the other two as predictor variable and get R^2 from SPSS.  I don't think there is anything in the output that could be used to compute R^2 for X1 Vs X2,D

Comment: This is a previous exam question where the data is not given. So I think there is a way!